# How do I prevent .net core service closing when I close electron window

Tags: asp.net-core, electron, electron.net

I am building an Electron app in .net and using the [Electron.net](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/tree/master/ElectronNET.WebApp) package and following their example web app.

But I would like to keep my .net web service running, even if the user closes the Electron window.

I'm planning to put a tray icon to allow the user to re-open the user interface if they've closed it.

But it looks like the BrowserWindow has somehow been set to terminate the application if the last window has been closed.

How can I keep it running?